# Cut,Copy, paste not working in tiny mce editor

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, text-editor

I have using tiny MCE editor to input the contents.If i want to cut, copy or paste any word it shows some error message like
   "Copy/Cut/Paste is not available in Mozilla and Firefox.Do you want more information about this issue?"

or  "Currently not supported by your browser, use keyboard shortcuts instead."..

How can i fix this problem. any one help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use Ctrl+V etc. Untrusted javascript not being able to access the clipboard sounds like a good idea.

Comment: shortcuts are working well but i wants to use icons to manage the actions...

Comment: AFAIK FF simply doesn't support this featured out of the box. There are addons that allow this, but you can't rely on your users having them installed. Adding this feature is a bit annoying since it needs to prompt the user to confirm that he wants to allow clipboard access to a certain website.